# Can I use iptables to forward vm guest requests to host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, mysql, iptables

This is a bit complicated, but I have a Windows 7 vm (virtualbox) and I need create a persistent connection to the MySQL instance on my host machine.

Binding...
I can do this using mysql address binding in the host my.cnf and corresponding mapping on the vm, but every time I change networks (work, home, wireless, or wired) the IP address of my host machine changes and I have to reset the bind address on the host machine and everywhere else (I have sites on my host machine as well as the VM).

The Windows VM has a NAT adapter (as well as a bridged).  I'm using the NAT defined 'default gateway' 10.0.4.2 to target my host machine.  I confirmed this by adding '10.0.4.2 asiteonmyhostmachine.net' to the host file on the VM, and visiting the url.

I've tried played around with ip aliasing:

```
ifconfig lo:1 10.0.4.3 up
```

I've tried iptables, based on some other threads I've read:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d 10.0.4.2 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT-p tcp -s 10.0.4.2 --sport 3306 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I haven't had much luck and I feel like I'm fumbling around in the dark.  Using nmap I can see that port 3306 is not accessible from 10.0.4.2 so it seems none of the above have worked.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, but please also include a method to test your (proposed) solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`iptables` is likely not the tool to do what you wish.  However, you may want to use iptables to block access from the internet.

Network traffic on the `lo` device should not be routed to another device, even a virtual device.  It is likely that virtualbox has created a `br0` devices or some device with `br` in the name.  The IP address of this device would be your best choice to connect to mysql on.

The virtual server should be able to connect directly to the mysql server, if it is listening on a reachable address.  It is common for mysql to be configured to listen on the loopback (127.0.0.1) address as a security measure.  Use the command `sudo netstat -antp | grep mysql` to determine which IP addresses `mysql` is listening on.  If it is only listening on `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, you will need to adjust the mysql configuration. If it is listening on `0.0.0.0`, mysql will be reachable on any public address of your server.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons Mysql default does not allow remote access by root.

To allow access follow these steps:

Edit the configuration file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" and remove the restriction of remote access

Comment the following line:

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Give permission to root for connections from any IP:

```
mysql -u root -pROOTPASSWORD
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'ROOTPASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit
```

Mysql open port with Iptables:

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

After restarting the service, it is possible to connect to the root user from the virtual machine

Sources:

```
https://www.virtualbox.org/
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server
http://directory.apache.org/
http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/
```